# How to fix Wordpress redirect issue within Cakephp?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I have an older instance of CakePHP installed running my website.

WordPress is installed on `example.com/blog` and used to work fine until I tried to fix another issue where the homepage `example.com` would redirect to `example.com//` with double slashes. The issue is that it now redirects to `example.com/webroot/blog`.

Here are my htaccess files and directory structure:

**/var/www/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ html/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) html/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/html/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]   
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/html/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**/var/www/html/webroot/blog/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `/var/www/html/webroot/` your web root folder for `example.com` domain ? If so, you don't need htaccess in `/var/www/` and `/var/www/html/`. Then, in `/var/www/html/webroot/.htaccess`, since the two incriminated lines are commented, just try clearing your browser's cache and try again. I'd also add a condition in `/var/www/html/webroot/.htaccess` to leave `/blog/` requests untouched

Comment: Thanks @JustinIurman for the response. `/var/www/html` is my main website root using cakephp. `/var/www/html/webroot/blog` is the blog. What should I do?

Comment: That's odd. Have you made absolutely sure that you're not seeing cached redirects (dev tools + cache disabled while requesting, using curl)? Have you tried just disabling the .htaccess file by file to see which one is responsible for that redirect?

Comment: @JustinIurman how would i leave those requests untouched?

Comment: @janh i have disabled each file one by one and the `/var/www/html/.htaccess` file is the one that kills the redirect, but it throws a not found.

Comment: I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/ [NC]` and `RewriteRule    (.*) $1    [L]` in my `/var/www/.htaccess` but nothing changed and still redirects to /webroot/blog

Comment: if /var/www/html is your document root and has your cakephp app, why do you have the webroot folder / why isn't the blog directly in /var/www/html/blog? Also, what's the expected result? http://www.example.com/ loads /var/www/html/index.php, and anything below /blog/ goes to /var/www/html/webroot/blog/index.php (aka default WP)?

Comment: @janh you are correct on example.com loading `/var/www/html/index.php` and `/blog/` loading WP on `/var/www/html/webroot/blog/index.php`

Comment: Here is my apache rewrite log if that would help you find something wrong: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/ddb340214e3de8f7d925180e48652859/raw/7706d8ca40540e5476b0fe2e6b1ac83a349e2b41/gistfile1.txt

Comment: what was your fix before which it was working fine?

Comment: I suggest to remove the middle folder webroot if you won't add multiple projects under webroot.

Comment: Why include the wordpress blog in a subfolder of the CakePHP framework, why not use an APACHE Alias?

Comment: Thanks to all that took their time to help figure this out. The line in the apache config fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried it is not possible to do what you need with .htaccess files.

You must create an alias in Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

Alias "/blog" "/var/www/html/webroot/blog"

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3 alias:debug


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>


# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```